# write jquery ui slider value to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I would like to send the value of the jquery slider to the database. I know this question already has a lot of answers but none of them helped me.
**HTML**

```
<label for="input-sale6">price</label>
<input type="text" id="input-sale6" name="dog_price" readonly />
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 2000,
        step: 50,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#input-sale6").val("€" + ui.value);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#input-sale6").val("€" + ui.value); 
        } 
    });
    $("#input-sale6").val("€" + $("#slider").slider("value"));
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/106/

The php part works fine (`$_POST[dog_price]`). I just need to get the value.
I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: There is a range slider in HTML5: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php

Comment: @JoshuaK Thank you! I would like to use the jquery slider, if at all possible.

Comment: Ok. where do you struggle? if there is a form-tag wrapping the input field, the value should send to your php part. Can you pls show us your php code. I think you forgot the "-characters around dog_price. `$_POST[dog_type]` is wrong. it should be `$_POST["dog_type"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change the way you are accessing the slider value

```
$("#input-sale6").val("€" +$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value" ));
```

Thanks Joshua K

Now try this:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 100,
    min: 0,
    max: 2000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#input-sale6").val("€" + $("#slider").slider("option", "value"));
    },
    change: function(event, ui) { 
       $("#input-sale6").val("€" + $("#slider").slider("option", "value"));
    } 
});
$("#input-sale6").val("€" + $("#slider").slider("option", "value"));
```

it just worked for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/68ye3108/)

Comment: take a look at the fiddle. the input field is changed correctly